# Remove icon from view selector/navigation list in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

is it possible to remove the icon to the right of the personal views in Dynamics? I have created the to views at the top of the list "Aktive personkunder" and "Mine aktive personkunder". In english these are lists for Contacts and Customers.

I have been trying to change it from the powerapps designer and from the old classic customizations. I can not seem to find where I can change it.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jupjc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to remove icon indicator for personal views, you can convert it to system views as that is the only option to make the icon go away.